# How do I make this a on HOVER of Div fade on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make this on hover instead of on click and still be able to access the .shopping-cart div when my cursor leaves the #cart-line div. What is the best way to do this?

```
(function(){$("#cart-line").on("click", function() {
$(".shopping-cart").fadeToggle( "fast");}); })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event, jQuery has a [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) event.

The difference in syntax is that the `hover` event takes two handlers, `hoverin` and `hoverout`

```
$("div#ToHoverOver").hover(
//Hover in handler
function(){
    $(this).css("color", "red");
}, 
//Hover out handler
function(){
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(function(){
     var cart_line = document.getElementById("cart-line");

     cart_line.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
         $(".shopping-cart").fadeToggle( "fast");
     });

})();
```